# Android location application

Tags: android, geolocation

I'm creating an Android app which uses the current location of the device. In order to do that I developed an application using the following code to get the current location every 5 seconds.

```
import android.*;
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.media.audiofx.BassBoost;
import android.os.Build;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CurrentLocation extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button button;
    private TextView textView;

    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private LocationListener locationListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_current_location);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                textView.append("\n " + location.getLongitude() + " " + location.getLatitude());
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        };

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                        Manifest.permission.INTERNET
                }, 10);
                return;
            }
        }
        else{
            configureButton();
        }
        ;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode){
            case 10:
                if(grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                    configureButton();
        }
    }

    private void configureButton() {
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 5000, 0, locationListener);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

It worked perfectly fine the first time I installed this application in my device. But after that it is not working at all. It doesn't even ask to turn on the location service.
Can someone please help me with this. Thank you.

Comment: After click the button, check your logcat and post de result. Do you have any error? Do you have enabled your GPS?

Answer (score 1):

Before `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 5000, 0, locationListener);` you should check if GPS(Location services) is on. you can do it with below function:

```
public boolean isGPSOn() {
    boolean isOn = ((LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE))
            .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if (!isOn) {
        showGPSEnableDialog();
    }
    return isOn;
}
```

and if not working can show a dialog or directly redirect to settings to enable it. Well dialog is preferable. If user choose to enable the GPS on your dialog redirect to settings like this.

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
```